# Is there an API call in WordPress to remove the categories and author from static pages?

Tags: wordpress, carrington

I'm currently using the Carrington Blog theme, and it has a few things that I would like to remove from static pages. I would like to remove the "Posted in Uncategorized.", "By Thomas Owens  – August 13, 2009" (where Thomas Owens is the author and August 13, 2009 is the date of posting), and "Comments Off" from all static pages (since I used the control panel to disable commenting on these pages) while leaving them on the blog post pages.

However, I took a quick glance through the API and I didn't see (1) a method to do this and (2) what page actually generates this so I can edit that.

If a plugin is already made, I could use that, however it seems like it would be a fairly simple operation to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or modify (or create) the page.php in the theme's template folder

Comment: This is what I thought ceejayoz was suggesting, so I went that route. I still have more work to do, but it looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap those sections in your template files with:

```
if(!is_page()) {
  // posted by box etc.
}
```

Comment: Ah. That actually makes sense. However, there appear to be plenty of things with the theme, so I'll have to poke around, but it seems do-able.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it would be to create a css rule that hides the information...

Use Firebug to find the specific class that the information is contained within, and then use display:none; to hide it.

Something like:

```
.page .meta-data-category, .page .meta-data-author, .page .meta-data-comments {display: none;}
```

Without any link to your site, I cannot find the exact class names to hide.

Kory